# can't import "from rest_framework import serializers" show the unresolved reference

Tags: python, django

It will show the unresolved reference of "import rest_framework import serializers,import rest_framework import viewsets"

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Task(models.Model):

    task_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    task_desc=models.TextField(max_length=200)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.task_name
```

in serializer file have a problem for rest_framework and i am many more times create a new project for i think missing any file of rest_framework library

Serializers.py(file)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Task

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id','task_name','task_desc')
```

settings.py(file)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'TaskAPI',
    'rest_framework',
)
```

views.py(file)

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Task
from .Serializers import TaskSerializer


class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset= Task.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
    Serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

i am using

```
    python==3.6.4
    django==2.0.3
    djangorestframework==3.8.2
```

The rest_framework library is not usable in program. so what is the problem in my code or 
missing any steps. plz help me any one give a reply as sson as possible 
thank you

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. What I did is just ignore the linting signal and tried running the server after double/triple checking the rest of my code was ok.

i ran the commannd

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and it just worked, with the unresolved naming and everything.

What I think is happening is that the IDE is unable to figure out all the environment variables inside the virtual environment, since the IDE is just using the root environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

1. from your IDE (I use `pycharm`), mark your `source-directory`
2. create your `requirements.txt` file
3. try to `import` again from your IDE

Un example of `requirements.txt` for this problem could be:

```
Django~=3.1.7
djangorestframework~=3.12.2
```